# Layer of elements are preventing the mouseover to show title

Tags: css

Sorry for the title, couldn't think about a better description for now.

Situation: Mouse over the progress bar to show a title. The small area (in my real case it is bigger) from the gray that mix with the green did not show the title. Looks like the number is a layer ahead of the progress bar.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/w6fpszkx/

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">Title</div>
        <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 0px 15px 15px 15px;">
            <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 110px; line-height: 1;">82<span style="font-size: 23px;">%</span></p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div title="" data-html="true" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 82%" data-original-title="ON TIME<br><span class='label label-success' style='display: inline-block; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 5px;'>9 (82%)</span>">
                    <span>9 (82%)</span>
                </div>
                <div title="" data-html="true" class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 18%" data-original-title="EXPIRED<br><span class='label label-danger' style='display: inline-block; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 5px;'>2 (18%)</span>">
                    <span>2 (18%)</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to reduce the top and bottom gray area from the "82" number to the top and bottom limits of the numbert itself? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you require here. Can you post a example demo or something to better illustrate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you have to adjust better the `line-height` of your element.

```
.text-center {
    line-height: 0.75;
    }
```

(and I removed the value "1" you added as style online in the html)

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w6fpszkx/1/)**

**Edited:** But to be sure your tooltip will always show just add:

```
.progress {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

so your bar will always be OVER the number:

**[updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w6fpszkx/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for your time. But it still not working. If you mouse over the green bar just bellow the number, the tooltip will not show. Because the "invisible" area bellow and above the number still there.